# AWK print after match with multi search

Tags: shell, awk

i have a log as below need to parse with new format :

```
2018-08-14 12:07:06,410 - MAILER - INFO - Email sent! - (TEMPORARY PASSWORD: cristronaldode ) to ['cristronaldode@eeee.com'] - Message ID: 01010165369da693-216f985f-e1b0-4dc2-bcea-8a2cd275a506-000000 Result: {'MessageId': '01010165369da693-216f985f-e1b0-4dc2-bcea-8a2cd275a506-000000', 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '338', 'date': 'Tue, 14 Aug 2018 04:07:05 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '81bbc0c4-9f77-11e8-81fe-8502a68e3b7d', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'RequestId': '81bbc0c4-9f77-11e8-81fe-8502a68e3b7d', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}}
```

output :

```
2018-08-14 12:07:06,410|TEMPORARY PASSWORD: cristronaldode|cristronaldode@eeee.com|'HTTPStatusCode': 200|
```

i'm trying use awk and match function but don't know how can use multi match in 1 line. Thanks

Update: i was using this command for parsing field but because i'm seperating fields by space so need to correct field in all lines. so i want other solutions.

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$2"|"$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19"|"$21"|"$48,$49}' | sed -e 's/[()]//g' | sed -e 's/[][]//g'| sed -e 's/}//g'
```

Comment: Please add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

The field seperator of awk can be regex.

```
awk -F '[][)(}{ ]*' '{print $1,$2}' file
```

We do now delimit on all the brackets like characters and count multiple occurrences of those characters as one.

You can figure out what fields you have to use now.